# DB query that orders a collection by an association's attribute value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'd like to apply an `:order` filter to a db query based on an associated object's attribute.

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords 
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :score
  belongs_to :report 
end

class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword 
end
```

Here's my query to pull a report's keywords, ordered by the keyword's associated score value attribute.

```
@keywords = @report.keywords.all(:joins => :score, :order => "scores.value DESC")
```

It's not working. It's simply returning the collection of keywords in no specific order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your query is doing two different things. It is fetching all keywords from one report based on the report ID (`@report.keywords`). Then You are trying to make a join with keywords and scores.
Think about SQL, the thing you want is a join from report to the two other tables.

```
SELECT * FROM reports 
JOIN keywords ON reports.id = keywords.id 
JOIN scores ON keywords.id = scores.id
```

To translate this to rails, if you are using an updated version of it, you can do something like this:

```
@report.keywords.includes(:score).order("scores.value DESC")
```

Older version of rails is quite similar, i don't know how to do it without searching.

Comment: This worked for me `@report.keywords.includes(:score).order("scores.value DESC")`

Comment: That's great. Just compare the 2 queries generated to see the difference. =]

Comment: Yours didn't work for me. It was giving me an error saying `Report` had no includes method. If you change your answer to what I said worked for me, I'll mark it right!